# Howland current source with voltage reference

Tags: current-source, bias, biasing

I need a precision current pump for small ac signals(50uA) and i tried it in multisim with a howland topology. It works however i need the load to not be grounded but bound to a bias voltage.

Here i show the layout.I want a non- inverting topology. Also,i have already biased the input AC signal to this DC and i have this DC available as a low-impedance voltage source. For me, the DC bias is 2.5V, with the load tied to this voltage, and Vs is 5V.
[image: ,]

Comment: Not having any luck doesn't help anyone understand what problem you found.

Comment: _"For what i want to achieve,i tried to add DC-bias to pins 2,3"_ - why?

Comment: @Andyaka,@Bruce Yeah basically i meant i have no clue XD. What i want is,bias the load to a DC point that i have already biased the input signal to. I have this voltage available as a low impedance source. Also, the topology must be non-inverting, like here.

Comment: I suppose the question is clear now, why not unlock it, i want to see more answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the classic Howland source here; it seems to me to be the so-called "improved Howland source". The ideas behind the two circuits are completely different. In the latter (this) case, the op-amp voltage follows with a constant shift (across constant resistance) the load voltage. Thus it adds "helping" voltage in series to the load voltage to compensate the undesired load variations (resistance, voltage...) In the classic Howland pump additional "helping" current is added (injected) in parallel to the load to help the imperfect input current source.

[image: Howland current source with shifted load]

So there is no problem to shift the load ground; the current will not change since the op-amp will shift its output voltage to compensate the load bias. Only another follower can be put at the circuit non-inverting input to isolate the input voltage.

Comment: I gotta think about this a bit.  The analysis I've done for a Howland current source always assumes a current flow, of some amount, from the reference (Vin) through R3 and R4 through the load RL.  With that extra op amp in there, to the right of R4, that current flow can't occur.

Comment: The voltage divider R3-R4 can be high resistive enough so to remove the voltage follower on the right. The input voltage source usually has low output resistance; so the voltage follower on the left can be also removed. It seems, the original "improved Howland pump" will do a good job...

Comment: It won't work . It's supposed to give a 8mV voltage swing to this 200Ω load .
Here is pictures. https://flic.kr/s/aHsmKbKuEn

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what won't work... Can you be more specific?

Comment: In the pictures i pasted you will see that the voltage swing is tiny(multisim oscilloscope). It is 8mV at the original circuit i uploaded.

Comment: Oh my god. When trying your circuit in multisim i mistakenly placed the lower opamp be from another IC and it was unpowered. It works now! Note : to the left of R1 is the Vbias,right?

Comment: @frizstyler Yes, R1 can be used as a second input for Vbias. I'm glad it works:)

Answer (score 1):

Biasing the load affects the input voltage controlled current since the input voltage is ground referenced, the Bias must also be added to the input with the correct ratio to cancel the effect.

If your CMOS OP AMP input bias currents affect the CC offset, then scale all the R values to lower values and attenuate the input.
[image]
 [My design here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%2027.727228452313398%2058%205%2050%0Aa%20752%20192%20864%20192%208%2015%20-15%201000000%204.21896550976455%204.219086949342424%20100000%0Aw%20864%20192%20864%20128%202%0Aw%20864%20192%20864%20256%200%0Ar%20752%20256%20864%20256%200%20100000%0Ar%20752%20128%20864%20128%200%20500000%0Ar%20752%20128%20640%20128%200%20500000%0Ar%20640%20256%20752%20256%200%2067000%0Aw%20752%20208%20752%20256%202%0AR%20640%20128%20640%2080%200%201%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20752%20128%20752%20176%202%0Aw%20752%20256%20752%20352%201%0Ar%20752%20352%20640%20352%200%2050000%0As%20752%20400%20640%20400%200%201%20false%0Aw%20752%20352%20752%20400%200%0Ag%20480%20144%20480%20176%200%0Aw%20640%20256%20640%20352%200%0Ax%20683%2099%20703%20102%204%2016%20R1%0Ax%20796%2099%20816%20102%204%2016%20R2%0Ax%20681%20291%20701%20294%204%2016%20R3%0Ax%20794%20291%20814%20294%204%2016%20R4%0Ax%20671%20387%20701%20390%204%2016%20load%0AR%20640%20256%20480%20320%200%200%2040%201.95%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20640%20352%20640%20400%200%0A403%20912%20224%201040%20288%200%2010_64_0_4354_5_0.1_0_2_10_3%0A403%20912%20320%201040%20384%200%2010_64_0_12545_0.0001_0.0001_0_2_10_3%0Aa%20544%20192%20640%20192%208%2015%20-15%201000000%201.9499415017549473%201.95%20100000%0Ar%20640%20144%20544%20144%200%201000000%0Ar%20544%20144%20480%20144%200%20500000%0Aw%20544%20208%20544%20256%200%0Aw%20640%20256%20544%20256%200%0Ar%20752%20176%20640%20176%200%201000000%0Aw%20544%20144%20544%20176%200%0Aw%20640%20144%20640%20176%202%0Aw%20640%20176%20640%20192%200%0A403%20912%20144%201040%20208%200%208_64_0_4354_5_0.1_0_2_8_3%0Ax%20896%2053%20955%2056%204%208%20Tony%5Cs12%5CsDec%5Cs2019%0A38%208%200%20-5%205%20Voltage%0A38%2021%200%200%205%20Vref%0A) Your mileage may vary.

### Design Specs

- 10uA /Volt CC source  0 to 50uA  or +/-50uA   0 to 5V slider
- Any Bias voltage .  0 to 5V slider.
- Any Load Resistance . Chose 50kohms to 0 ohms (switch)
- Rail to Rail CMOS Op Amps, low noise, low bias current
- MF resistors 0.2%

**Rev A specs**   (assumed, not verified)
Vin offset = 2.5Vdc
Vout offset =2.5Vdc
Single supply OA R2R
Output error with ideal parts 0.2%
Non-inverting current gain

[Simulation results verified here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%205.934295036739208%2058%205%2050%0Aa%20752%20192%20864%20192%208%2015%20-15%201000000%202.49737858610247%202.497390512570448%20100000%0Aw%20864%20192%20864%20144%202%0Aw%20864%20192%20864%20288%200%0Ar%20752%20288%20864%20288%200%20100000%0Ar%20752%20144%20864%20144%200%201000000%0Ar%20544%20144%20496%20144%200%20150000%0Aw%20752%20208%20752%20288%202%0AR%20496%20144%20496%20208%200%203%2040%200.3%202.5%200%200.5%0Aw%20752%20144%20752%20176%202%0Aw%20640%20288%20672%20288%202%0Ar%20752%20288%20672%20288%200%20200%0Ax%20804%20260%20824%20263%204%2016%20R1%0Ax%20703%20261%20723%20264%204%2016%20R2%0Ax%20797%20118%20817%20121%204%2016%20R3%0Ax%20686%20119%20706%20122%204%2016%20R4%0Ax%20700%20317%20730%20320%204%2016%20load%0AR%20544%20288%20480%20288%200%200%2040%202.5%200%200%200.5%0A403%20608%20320%20736%20384%200%209_64_0_12545_0.0001_0.0001_0_2_9_3%0Aa%20544%20192%20640%20192%208%2015%20-15%201000000%202.499961978896256%202.5%20100000%0Ar%20640%20144%20544%20144%200%201000000%0Aw%20544%20208%20544%20288%200%0Aw%20640%20288%20544%20288%200%0Ar%20752%20144%20640%20144%200%201000000%0Aw%20544%20144%20544%20176%202%0Aw%20640%20144%20640%20176%202%0Aw%20640%20176%20640%20192%200%0A403%20416%20176%20544%20240%200%207_64_0_12546_2.799999720107282_0.0001_0_2_7_3%0Ax%20914%20375%20973%20378%204%208%20Tony%5Cs12%5CsDec%5Cs2019%0Ax%20586%20120%20606%20123%204%2016%20R5%0Ax%20507%20120%20527%20123%204%2016%20R6%0A403%20624%20176%20704%20224%200%2025_64_0_4354_5_0.1_0_2_25_3%0A403%20880%20176%201008%20240%200%202_64_0_4354_5_0.1_0_2_2_3%0Ax%20911%20363%20975%20366%204%208%20Rev%5CsA%5Cs22%5CsDec%5Cs2019%0Ap%20752%20288%20784%20336%201%204%0Ap%20496%20144%20400%20144%201%204%0A38%207%200%20-5%205%20Voltage%0A38%2016%200%200%205%20Vref%0A) 
[image]

Comment: Thank you. However this is an inverting topology and i was hoping for a non-inverting?

Comment: good specs with tolerances are better than hope

Comment: specs are a 600mV p-p AC source that is biased to 2.5vDC and i want a 40 uA p-p swing through a 200Ω resistor. So i used R1 in my schematic above =15KΩ

Comment: Specs go in the question as an edit and include output DC Voltage. If =0V on 200 Ohm , then you need bipolar supplies., so I chose 200 Ohms to 2.5V instead, which means you need an LDO or Vdd/2 buffer